# Completely changing a question vs asking a new question

Tags: discussion, questions, editing, best-practices

When a OP has one of their questions closed one of the main desirable outcomes is for the OP to edit the question to address the issues that led to the closure. However, where should we draw the line between editing an existing question and asking a new question?

In this case

[How light wave have thermal effect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/485084/)

I think that the edits would be more appropriate for a new question as they completely changed the question. This means that the answers (including mine) which were valid answers to the original question now are not even remotely addressing the edited question.

If another user had made these edits then I would simply roll back the edits, but since the OP made the edits I am hesitant and considering deleting my answer instead. But I find that I am rather irritated by the whole situation since deleting a valid answer to the original question will cost me points.

I think that the best course would be for the OP to ask a new question, but what is the actual policy? Shall I roll back the question or delete my now off topic answer?

Comment: Related: *[Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478)*

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4147/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions should not be edited in a way that invalidates existing answers. I have rolled back the edit in this particular case, and all users should roll back such edits when they see them.

Comment: And that applies even for the OP?

Comment: @Dale Yes. If OP has a new question, they can simply ask a new question. (If they can't because they are blocked by the system from asking further questions, then they are trying to circumvent that restriction, which we also shouldn't accommodate)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the clarification.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/485084/revisions Probably should be rolled back to rev 6 and closed as a duplicate again...